# Transposing in Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I am trying to transpose in pandas. I have something that looks like this:

A B C D E F G H I
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I want it to look like this:

A 1

B 2

C 3

D 4

E 5

F 6

G 7

H 8

I 9

Comment: If you have a `DataFrame`, just use the `transpose` method...

Comment: pandas has a native transpose function...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas-dataframe-t) or [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas-dataframe-transpose):

```
df.T
```

or

```
df.transpose()
```

Input:

```
A B C D E F G H I
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Output:

```
   0
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
E  5
F  6
G  7
H  8
I  9
```